# Is it a bad idea to allow magento upload SVG file for CMS page?

Tags: file-upload, svg

One of my user request to ask me to make the Magento able to upload svg file to the CMS. I did some research, some say security issue, but didn't tell much what kind of security issue it may happen. Anyone can give me a clear advice? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

So if you let your admin upload it, or say it another way, the trusted users upload it then it's alright, no problem.

Handling that to users who we don't know, therefore, cannot be trusted is dangerous.

I myself haven't implemented the upload svg guard but you may check this answer, it listed several ways to help prevent the risk
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/192736